# Changing Drush make default subdir for install profiles

Tags: 7, drush

I have a drush make file which has a default subdir for projects:

```
defaults[projects][subdir] = contrib
```

This places all modules into the `sites/all/modules/contrib` folder, which is great.

The trouble is, it also places my install profiles into the `profiles/contrib` folder.  Now when I run `drush site-install`, it doesn't work because the install profile is in the wrong folder.

Is there any way to tell drush make to NOT put the install profiles into a subdir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this and the following works:

```
projects[my_install_profile][subdir] = ""
```