# How to install an existing Drupal profile with drush?

Tags: drush, installation-profiles

Seems like searching for the answer on Google just leads me to how to create make files and profiles.

I know how to do that.
I also know how to install Drupal with drush.

But I want to install one of the many existing Drupal profiles, like Drupal Commons, Commerce Kick Start, etc. with drush.

I would have thought it would have been just an easy process to find the profile's makefile and run that. Drush will take care of the rest.
But I can't find the repositories where these makefiles sits.

Some direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To build on what Patrick said, if the profile is **not** already in your profile directory, you can download it with Drush dl:

`drush dl drupal --drupal-project-rename=drupal
cd drupal
drush dl commons
drush site-install commons --db-url=mysql://user:pwd@localhost/db_name --site-name=Example --account-name=admin --account-pass=pwd`

You do not need to run `drush make`, because drupal.org runs it prior to making the profile available for download.  Thus, when you run `drush dl commons`, you get all of the components that the Drupal Commons distribution needs to install.

Comment: OK, we getting somewhere. Seems like my dependency of wanting just a makefile for something like 'Commons' to run is out the door. so this leads to another question: Where can I find a list of profiles I can do like this?

Comment: Run `drush dl commons` as I suggest above; you will find the makefile inside of the files that are downloaded.  If you move it to another folder, you could then run drush make on it to rebuild the distribution.  You might also want to look at https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_generate

Answer (score 1):

If the profile is already in your drupal/profiles directory you can just pass it into site-install.

```
drush site-install your_profile --db-url=mysql://user:pwd@localhost/db_name --site-name=Example --account-name=admin --account-pass=pwd
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want to have the need to download the whole profile first. I want to run the drush makefile that will do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Drush Make](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/drush-make/info) is what you're looking for?

There are various questions (and answers) tagged with [drush-make](/questions/tagged/drush-make).

And the answer to [Changing Drush make default subdir for install profiles](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138891) may also help.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I know drush-make. Now I want to drush-make  one of the the many installation profiles that is already out there. Some thing like drush make drupal-commons.makefile (pseudo example), and the rest is taken care of. But where would I find the drupal-commons.makefile?