# Change profile makefile download location?

Tags: drush, installation-profiles

This is similar to [Changing Drush make default subdir for install profiles](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138891/changing-drush-make-default-subdir-for-install-profiles), but with a twist.  I'm using a set of nested profiles to inherit default modules, each with a makefile.  Unfortunately, this causes the modules specified in each profile to downloaded to that profile's /modules folder.  Is there any way to specify where files in a discovered .make should be placed (such as /sites/all/modules), even if in a profile?